# Ограничения событий для объекта на форме

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

На форме есть обработчик нажатия клавиши `Enter`, который обновляет объект `webBrowser` (и не только). Загруженная страница в объекте `webBrowser` имеет поле ввода. Если после ввода нажать `Enter`, то выполнится событие обновления `webBrowser`, а не передача данных поля на сервер. Как сделать ограничение для объекта `webBrowser`, чтобы событие формы не срабатывало, если активен `webBrowser`?

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        String tabName = null;
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                RenewMethod();
                //==other stuff
                return true;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Проверьте, стоит ли у вашей формы свойство `KeyPreview = false`.

Comment: Стоит true. Но дело в том, что у меня используется большое количество разных хоткеев. И все обрабатываются формой. А вот сейчас получилось одно как исключение.

Comment: Попробуйте в обработчике нажатия клавиши Enter проверять в фокусе ли компонент webbrowser и если это так - ничего не делать по нажатию: if (webBrowser1.Focused) {return; }

Comment: Анатолий, спасибо большое. Такой способ подходит.

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev преобразуйте ваш комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменения предложил Анатолий Николаев в комментарии к вопросу:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    String tabName = null;
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Enter: // Вот оно
            if (webBrowser.Focused)
               return true; //
            RenewMethod();
            //==other stuff
            return true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Влад, да, спасибо)